# Can [spam] handle [spam-handling]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

Here on meta, we have separate [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) and [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling) tags. They are not even synonyms. [A few questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/spam+spam-handling) are even tagged with both of them.

Since only seven questions in total are currently tagged [spam](/questions/tagged/spam), three of which are *also* tagged [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling), and [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling) is the tag we've pretty much all been using lately, you might be wondering why I'm even asking this, rather than just retagging them all [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling).

The reason is that **I'd like to make [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) the main tag and [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling) the synonym**, for two reasons:

1. [I've heard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40950257#40950257) that's what other [child metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298735/what-is-child-meta-in-stackexchange) use for this.***** I guess a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query could show this rigorously, but a quick look through the [top sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)' child metas seems to confirm it. The [network-wide meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) also uses *spam* and not *spam-handling*.
2. There hasn't been a difference between [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) and [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling). But someone may ask a question about the [promotions policy](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion), along the lines of *"Would it be spam if I...?"* There, the topic of [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) applies, but the question is not really about [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling). I don't think we want the granularity of separate tags, and [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) is the slightly broader one, so I think we should use that.

So long as we make one of the two tags a synonym of the other, I think the outcome is fine. But I think it would be *best* if we used [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) as the main tag.

One benefit of making them synonyms instead of removing one of the tags from all the questions that have it is that we can avoid bumping a whole bunch of meta questions by editing (seven to detag [spam](/questions/tagged/spam), and far more to detag [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling)). Bumping multiple meta questions has quite a visible effect since [meta is slow](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16695/why-is-meta-slow), though it's not actually *harmful* to do so.

A more important benefit of making them synonyms is that either tag is likely to come back regardless of what gets decided here: [spam-handling](/questions/tagged/spam-handling) out of habit, and [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) because it's the obvious choice.

***** <sub>This post [originally stated](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/17424/revisions) that the *spam* tag was one of the tags that new sites' child metas are *created* with, but that appears [not to be the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233898/what-tags-exist-by-default-on-child-metas).</sub>